# jQuery submit form on checkbox click

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to submit a form whenever checkboxes are clicked (I already have ajax set up with Rails) - this means even if it gets unchecked. Also I never want the click handler to unbind, so a user can click a checkbox as many times and the form will get submitted each time.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

The above code works fine, but it stops working after the first click. How would I make it so that the above code will work even when a user clicks a checkbox more than once?

**EDIT:**

I am replacing the contents of the form (including the checkboxes) on submission of the form.

Comment: what exactly happens in the 2nd click? I believe this might be a popup blocking issue...

Comment: it should work on the second click also, are there any errors or other kind of notifications ?

Comment: Nothing happens on the second click at all

Comment: What’s the effect of the AJAX request? Does anything on the page get updated or replaced?

Comment: @Sidnicious I'm replacing the contents of the form (including the checkboxes)

Comment: @Languages Then the event was bound to the *old* checkbox, not the new one. You need to re-bind the event handler after the form is reloaded, or use `.live` or `.delegate` to bind an event handler to the closest parent parent element of the form that *doesn’t* get replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox').live('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: why do you think this will work? I don't see a problem that `live` can solve. Also, you missed a quote symbol

Comment: Additionally, you need to supply an event name to `live` for this to by syntactically correct.

Comment: Ugh long day - code fixed. Depending on how his form is being submitted, I've had issues in the past with event bindings being lost, and applying a future-proof event observer like live or delegate solved the issue.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Looks like this answer is actually correct, judging by the OP's most recent comment, +1.